# Where is node repl default directory and how to change it?

Tags: node.js, node-repl

I'm reloading my script a lot and would like to change the default directory where node repl is looking at so that I don't have to provide the whole path.

Is that possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The node.js REPL uses the current working directory (the directory in which you invoked the REPL) as a base when you use relative paths.

Comment: What does "current working" mean? How do I change the working directory?

Comment: With `cd path/to/elsewhere`

Comment: "current working directory" is the directory in which you started the REPL.